# Maximal norm of matrix interacted with a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $N\times N$ matrix with all entries strictly positive and $v$ a nonnegative $N\times 1$ vector, and let $\mathcal{D}\left\{ v\right\}$  be the diagonal matrix with entries $v_{k}$. Consider the object $$\phi(A)\equiv\sup_{||v||=1,v\geq0}||\left(\mathcal{D}\left\{ Av\right\} \right)^{-1}A\mathcal{D}\left\{ Av\right\} ||$$ for some matrix norm. Is this a known characteristic of a matrix? I see that if $A$ is diagonal then $\phi(A)=\rho(A)$ (if using the spectral norm), but I don't think this is true more generally.

Comment: What happens if $v \in \ker A$ ?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to avoid this possibility.